# mvccontrib gridview, using new mvc3 syntax issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib-grid

I've upgraded from mvc 2 to mvc 3. I've grabbed the new mvc contrib dll's for mvc 3 from here 
http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases

I'm having some issues with the new mvc grid syntax. See attached. 
[image]

Does anyone know the new syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{Html
    .Grid(Model.PagedList)
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(cust => cust.Id);
        column.For(cust => cust.Surname);
        column.For(cust => cust.DateOfBirth);
    })
    .Render();
}
```